# Basic hierarchical dependency diagram of (slightly) complex intertwined systems

Tags: dependencies

I have just been tasked with creating a dependency list of all of my companies web sites, underlying pages/functions and the dependencies they have on other systems, web services, etc.

This is for our testing team to be able to identify the impact that changes in area A will have on application A.
On a very basic level, things would looks something like below;

```
Application
 -Page
  -Function
   -Dependency
```

However, due to nested dependencies, things can get a bit more convoluted, like;

```
Application
 -Page
  -Function
   -Dependency
    -Function
     -Dependency
  -Function
   -Dependency
    -Function
   -Dependency
```

I'm trying to work out the best way to collate & structure this data.
There's no need to delve into the parameters for each of the functions, etc, the point is simply to illustrate the fact there is a dependency.

I was thinking an Excel table at first, possibly an XML file where each element has a type set (i.e. application, function, dependency, etc) or even to use SQL (this would also allow something like "select * from functions where dependency = 'blah'" but my experience in planning this type of thing is close to zero (I'm sure this post already illustrates this!)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Pat.